# Allow access to one directory when all others require authorisation

Tags: apache-2.2, directory, authorization

I have an Apache config that restricts access to to a website, using the following code -

```
<Directory /var/www/html/website/test/>
        AuthName "Dyne Drewett Test Site"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /usr/local/etc/apache/.htpasswd
        require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Does anybody know how I can amend this to allow full, unauthorised access to one directory under `/test/`? Thanks.

**Update**

After some help from **@dunxd** I now have this, which I'm guessing must be wrong as I'm still getting the 401 error when going to the page that is requested (found with the `/dyne_drewett/` directory). Any further help would be great.

```
# Main directory rules
<Directory /var/www/html/website/test/>

    # General access to the site
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from 192.168.1

    # Authorisation settings
        AuthName "Dyne Drewett Test Site"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /usr/local/etc/apache/.htpasswd
        require valid-user

</Directory>

# Theme directory rules
<Directory /var/www/html/website/test/wp-content/themes/dyne_drewett/>

    # General access to the folder
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

    # Authorisation settings
        AuthType None
        require all granted

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of ways of achieving this.

Simplest way is to create another Directory entry for the subdirectory with [AuthType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authn_core.html#authtype) set to None like this:

```
<Directory /test/public>
AuthType None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Another approach uses a different URL pointing to the directory.  In [Apache docs for Directory directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) there is a comment saying:

> Be careful with the directory-path arguments: They have to literally
>   match the filesystem path which Apache httpd uses to access the files.
>   Directives applied to a particular  will not apply to files
>   accessed from that same directory via a different path, such as via
>   different symbolic links.

You could use that to your advantage here - create a symlink from /allowed/ to your subdirectory under /test/ and use that URL to point to the directory.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've updated my question with all `<directory>` entries from my config, as I still can't get it to work. I'd be grateful if you could take a look and let me know if anything looks incorrect. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidGard I'm not sure why your `<directory>` rules aren't working. I copied your rules and they worked for me. The difference I have is that I don't have a slash at the end of the directory path